# Client can't connect to the server online

Tags: java, network-programming, server, client, port

I've been searching around Stackoverflow and google trying to figure out how I manage to make it possible for people using a different internet connection to connect to my server with my client software. My Chat Server-client works perfectly between different computers on the same local network.

I've tried to port forward on different ports in range of 8000-9000 with TCP/UDP. I've also tried a lot of other stuff which I don't find useful in this post since it's just small changes in the code which didn't work.

Comment: You should provide some code ...

Comment: Even though it's working perfectly on a local network? I've been told that it has something to do with the router/modem and firewalls?

Comment: Most likely. You should learn about computer networking.

Comment: You need to make your system accessible on the Internet! This can be done by configuring the router/system(which is off-topic here).